# Deploying .NET Core in IIS without publishing manually

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have a number of services which run via IIS and that are worked on daily.  On my local machine these are run via IIS.  When I was using .NET Framework this was easy, I would point to the source folder and it just worked.  Now with .NET Core I must manually "publish" every time I make a change.  Is there some way to automatically publish when I build or when changes are made?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Azure Devops (VSTS) account and configure build and release triggers.
This will basically pull your repository every-time you push to certain branch and then follow the build and release process you configured to deploy your solution to your IIS.

Here is a link with some more details to help you : https://medium.com/@taithienbo/build-and-deploy-an-asp-net-core-app-running-on-iis-using-azure-pipelines-e675041f62d4

Comment: DevOps won't be able to deploy to my local machine and that whole process is much more complicated than right-clicking and clicking publish.  This is about a local dev environment and IIS, nothing more.